# VBA - Autofilter increases sheet size substantially

Tags: excel, vba

I have a "Sheet1" that looks like this:

[image: Sheet1]

My exemplatory data has 73 rows. Now, I want to filter this data set based on some columns and copy the filtered data set to another sheet "Sheet2". Using the code from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934821/vba-for-filtering-columns) (with some adjustments), I came up with the following code:

```
Option Explicit
'Filter input sheet (Sheet1) and copy filtered sheet to new sheet
Sub FilterAndCopySheet1()
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934821/vba-for-filtering-columns

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Offset(0).ClearContents

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter

            'Array filter from NameList
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="USD", Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="OCR", Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="Europe", Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:="Finance", Operator:=xlFilterValues
            LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
                    Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

The code works just fine. The only problem is that the file size increases from roughly 25Kb to 25MB. Of course, this slows everything down.

So my questions are: Why does this code result in such an increase? Is my code not efficient? Or is it an inherent problem of the auto-filter method? If so, what would alternatives be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around with it a little bit longer and having read about formats going crazy in Excel, I found out that these lines of code at the end of the sub solve the problem:

```
With Sheets("Sheets2")
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).Clear
    .Range(.Cells(1, 9), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).Clear
End With
```

Still, it would be interesting where the original code adds so much unwanted formatting that the sample size explodes.