# Copying only visible from one sheet to another (with blanks in between)

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies editing .I have this below code which copies data of one row from 1 sheet to another (there are blanks in between). The code works fine, however I would like it copy only visible fields from sheet 1 (filters already applied).

This is copying the entire column U irrespective of the filters applied (filters are applied I column 10 and 38)

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set SrcRng = .Range(.Cells(1, "U"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp))
End With
Worksheets("Sheet2").range("I1").Resize(SrcRng.Rows.Count, 1).Value = SrcRng.Value'
```

Please help

Comment: not sure if you have filter in there wich you should add first `.Range("$A:$U").AutoFilter` or what columns you use. This post might point you in a direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934821/vba-for-filtering-columns. atm it looks like you try to filter Fields in one column `"U"`

Comment: you set your filter range to a sinlge column "U", how do you expect to run Filters on columns 8, 10 and 39 ? you have a range with 39 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub CopyVisible()
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim SrcRange As Range, CpyRng As Range
Dim LRow As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData 'Removes Previous Filters

With ws
    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row 'Check Col "H" for last data
    Set SrcRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LRow, 39)) 'Range with Data
        With SrcRng
            .AutoFilter Field:=39, Criteria1:="Blue"
            .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="Pass"
            .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="<>"
        End With
    For i = 1 To LRow 'Loop through all Rows
        If Not .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden Then 'Checks if Row is Hidden
            If CpyRng Is Nothing Then
                Set CpyRng = .Range("U" & i)
            Else
                Set CpyRng = Union(CpyRng, .Range("U" & i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With
ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData 'Remove Filters
CpyRng.Copy ws2.Range("I1") 'Copy and Paste
End Sub
```

Will apply filters to all Columns from 1 to 39 and filter with the wanted criteria. Creates range with all visible rows in Col `U` and paste them into `Sheet2` into Col `I`.

Comment: Thanks fo this ,But I would want only Column U in sheet 1 to be copied to Column I in Sheet 2 is that possible?